# A Regex for Group Matching in Java

Tags: java, regex

I have a row of data that is split by tabs. I want to do a counted matching: first three are in group 1, second three are in group 2, and last one in group 3.

```
0   0   1998-09-21 CD   O   O   B-Num
```

I'm not an expert in regex but I came up with this:

`^(\S*)[\t,]*(\S*)[\t,]*(\S*)[\t,]*(\S*)[\t,]*(\S*)[\t,]*(\S*)[\t,]*(\S*)[\t,]*(.*)$`

This will only split everything into seven pieces, which does not meet the requirement..anyone knows how to do tasks like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the way you're capturing a little to this:

```
^(\S*[\t,]*\S*[\t,]*\S*)[\t,]*(\S*[\t,]*\S*[\t,]*\S*)[\t,]*(\S*)$
 ^---------------------^      ^---------------------^      ^---^
```

Also, you might want to change some of the quantifiers to `+`. having all `*` means that it will also attempt to match an empty string.

Comment: Emmm..may I ask what does "capturing" mean?

Comment: @WindDweller capturing in simple terms means storing the match into a particular variable for later use. Parentheses are used to indicate capture groups.